# IAccessible type not defined visual basic

Tags: vba, vb6

I have a old project in VB6

I want to use MSAA Accessebility and i get an error on this line:

```
Private Declare Function AccessibleChildren Lib "oleacc" (ByVal paccContainer As IAccessible, ByVal iChildStart As Long, ByVal cChildren As Long, rgvarChildren As Variant, pcObtained As Long) As Long
```

error: `type not defined`

I think IAccessible type not defined , how to correctly define it and use in VB6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this article on brainbell.com](http://www.brainbell.com/tutors/Visual_Basic/Why_Should_I_Use_Active_Accessibility.htm), you must add a reference to oleacc.dll in order to be able to use the IAccessible type:

> Before you start building your project you of course need to load the
>   Microsoft Active Accessibility SDK (MSAASDK). After you've loaded the
>   SDK, you must create a reference in your project to the Accessibility
>   DLL, OLEACC.DLL.
>
> Select References from the Project menu, then click
>   the Browse button to find the OLEACC.DLL file. By default this file is
>   located in the \Windows\System folder.
>
> Once you've created the
>   reference, you can view the Accessibility library through the Object
>   Browser in Visual Basic.
>
> When you select Accessibility from the
>   Project/Library drop-down list in the Object Browser, you won't see
>   anything in the Classes or Member Of lists because the Accessibility
>   settings are hidden. You need to right-click in the Members Of pane
>   and select Show Hidden Members to view the Accessibility classes and
>   members.

Comment: May you help me with next question:22305039 ?