# How to Resolve IAccessible Type Not Defined Error

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I am new to Visual Studio (currently using a Visual Basic Forms starter application) and have been experiencing the issue addressed in [IAccessible type not defined visual basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297243/iaccessible-type-not-defined-visual-basic)

Here I am attempting to import the `AccessibleObjectFromWindow` function via a `Declare` statement within my code, as such:

```
Private Declare Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "oleacc.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal dwId As Long, ByRef riid As Guid, ByRef ppvObject As IAccessible) As Long
Dim obj As IAccessible
'Save the IAccessible interface pointer onto obj
Call AccessibleObjectFromWindow({WINDOW_HANDLE}, 0, guid, obj)
```

However, the `IAccessible` type is not available within my project and the solution to import the olacc.dll library located in the System32 folder described in the previous post (linked above) yielded a warning messagebox claiming "The reference is invalid or unsupported".

Is there any way I can import the `IAccessible` Type, or bypass the issue altogether and interact with the ppvObject I will  using an ambigious type (ie Object/Variant)? What is the best approach to addressing this issue?

Comment: Visual Studio does not use VB6! I assume it uses Vb.Net which is a different language.

Comment: @[John Eason] Thanks for pointing that out, I just updated my question with the appropriate tags.

Comment: Ok. Hopefully you'll get some answers now. (MS ended support for the VB6 IDE on April 8, 2008 although lots of folks still use and have to support it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `Imports Accessibility`?

IAccessible is in [Accessibility Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/accessibility?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)